# C pointers, inserting elements to HEAD of linked list

Tags: c, pointers

I am working on a problem in the K&R book (#6.3) where the user inputs a sequence of words, and you have to create a list of these words along with the lines that each one appears on. It's supposed to involve structures so these are the ones I have right now:

```
struct entry {
    int line; 
    int count; 
    struct entry *next; 
};

struct word {
    char *str;  
    struct entry *lines; 
    struct word *next; 
}; 

static struct word *wordlist = NULL;    // GLOBAL WORDLIST
```

However when I input something and the program tries to add a new entry to the structure (which is somewhat like a linked list), there is a problem and the program terminates with no error message. Code for that:

```
void add_entry(char *word, int line)
{
    if (word == NULL || line <= 0 || is_blocked_word(word))
        return;

    struct word *w; 
    for (w = wordlist; w != NULL && w->next != NULL && !strcmp(w->str, word); w = w->next); 

    // If word is found in the wordlist, then update the entry
    if (w != NULL) {
        struct entry *v; 
        for (v = w->lines; v != NULL && v->next != NULL && v->line != line; v = v->next); 

        if (v == NULL) {
            struct entry *new = (struct entry*) malloc(sizeof(struct entry)); 
            new->line = line;
            new->count = 1;
            new->next = NULL; 

            if (w->lines == NULL)
                w->lines = new; 
            else
                v->next = new; 
        }
        else v->count++; 
    }

    // If word is not found in the word list, then create a new entry for it
    else {
        struct word *new = (struct word*) malloc(sizeof(struct word)); 
        new->lines = (struct entry*) malloc(sizeof(struct entry)); 
        new->next = NULL; 
        new->str = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(word)); 
        new->lines->line = line; 
        new->lines->count = 1; 
        new->lines->next = NULL; 
        strcpy(new->str, word); 

        // If the word list is empty, then populate head first before populating the "next" entry
        if (wordlist == NULL) 
            wordlist = new; 
        else 
            w->next = new;
    }
}
```

The program terminates even after adding just the first word to `wordlist`. This is on the line that says `if (wordlist == NULL) wordlist = new;` where `new` contains the pointer to a valid structure that I malloc'ed. How can this be possible?

As far as I know it's a problem with my pointer usage but I'm not sure where exactly it lies. Can someone help?

Comment: change `new->str = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(word));` to `new->str = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * (1+strlen(word)));`

Comment: Is this C or C++. It makes a difference, particularly in your invocation of `malloc()` (which has little place bing in C++ code in the first place). You're citing K&R, which leads me to believe you need to lose the C++ tag from this question.

Comment: @Ryan do not use new as variable name, change it

Comment: I had a feeling. a variable called `new` would not play nice in a C++ world. That said, change that line again, only lose the cast in front of `malloc()`. It isn't needed.

Comment: If it's C and not C++, "new" is a fine and legal variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some fairly evident, and some not-so-evident things.

**The for-loop limit for `w` stops one short**

```
for (w = wordlist; w != NULL && w->next != NULL && !strcmp(w->str, word); w = w->next);
```

This will start with the first and continue *until*

1. We have run out of nodes
2. We have *almost* (one short) run out of nodes.
3. The word in the current node does NOT match

**Almost the same problem, different for-loop**

```
for (v = w->lines; v != NULL && v->next != NULL && v->line != line; v = v->next);
```

As above, this has similar attributes (but not the third option, as this correctly *continues* so long as the line numbers do not match. The prior loop broke as soon as *any* word did not match.

And that is in the first ten lines of this function.

**String allocation size fails to account for the nulchar terminator**

This falls short by one char of the allocation size needed for a zero-terminated string:

```
malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(word))
```

You always need space for the terminator. The easiest way to remember that is to consider how many chars are needed for a zero-length C string? Answer: one, because the terminator needs to go somewhere. After that is simply `length+1`

---

One possible way to do this is via a pointer-to-pointer approach, shown below:

```
void add_entry(const char *word, int line)
{
    if (word == NULL || line <= 0 || is_blocked_word(word))
        return;

    struct word **pp = &wordlist;
    for (; *pp && strcmp((*pp)->str, word); pp = &(*pp)->next);
    if (*pp)
    {
        // search for matching line number
        struct entry **vv = &(*pp)->lines;
        for (; *vv && (*vv)->line != line; vv = &(*vv)->next);
        if (!*vv)
        {
            *vv = malloc(sizeof(**vv));
            if (!*vv)
            {
                perror("Failed to allocate line entry.");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            (*vv)->count = 1;
            (*vv)->line = line;
            (*vv)->next = NULL;
        }
        else
        {   // found an entry. increment count.
            (*vv)->count++;
        }
    }
    else
    {   // no matching word. create a new word with a new line entry
        size_t len = strlen(word);
        *pp = malloc(sizeof(**pp));
        if (!*pp)
        {
            perror("Failed to allocate word entry.");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        (*pp)->lines = malloc(sizeof(*(*pp)->lines));
        if (!(*pp)->lines)
        {
            perror("Failed to allocate line count entry.");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        (*pp)->str = malloc(len + 1);
        if (!(*pp)->str)
        {
            perror("Failed to allocate word string entry.");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        (*pp)->lines->count = 1;
        (*pp)->lines->line = line;
        (*pp)->lines->next = NULL;
        (*pp)->next = NULL;
        memcpy((*pp)->str, word, len+1);
    }
}
```

**How It Works**

In both cases, we use a pointer-to-pointer. They are a most-hand construct when the desire is to perform tail-end insertion on a linked list without having to keep a "one-back" or "previous" pointer. Just like any pointer, they hold an address. Unlike a regular pointer-to-something, a pointer-to-pointer-to-something holds the address of another pointer. With it we can "loop" by initially setting it to the address of the head pointer, the entering the search.

```
struct word **pp = &wordlist;
for (; *pp && strcmp((*pp)->str, word); pp = &(*pp)->next);
```

Here we start with the address of our head pointer. the loop will terminate if the pointer *at the address held in `pp`* is NULL, or if the word actually matches. Otherwise it sets the address **of** (not the address *in*) the `next` pointer of the current node.If we run out of words and never find a match the loop will break, but with a most-handy consequence: `pp` contains the address of the pointer that we need to set to the new allocation. If the list were initially empty, *it contains the address of the head pointer.*

With that, we can then do this:

```
if (*pp)
{
    // search for matching line number
    struct entry **vv = &(*pp)->lines;
    for (; *vv && (*vv)->line != line; vv = &(*vv)->next);
```

Notice we use the same idea on the line-entry list. Either we're going to find an entry, or the loop will exit with `*vv` being `NULL`, and `vv` contains the address of the `next` pointer we want to set to our new allocation.

I *strongly* urge you to step through this code in a debugger line-by-line, and understand how it works. utilizing this technique has many redeeming qualities, among them the incredibly brief method of populating a forward-linked list in `O(n)` complexity *without* having to check for a head pointer or walking the list for each insertion **and** retaining the original order (as opposed to reversing the order as a stack-like solution would result):

```
struct node *head = NULL;

struct node **pp = &head;
while (get-data-for-our-list)
{
    *pp = malloc(sizeof(**pp));
    // TODO: populate (*pp)->members here
    pp = &(*pp)->next;
}
*pp = NULL;
```